# Cash On Delivery plugin is not available in Payment Methods page in NopCommerrce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, plugins, nopcommerce

1. I have downloaded the source of Nop.Plugin.Payments.CashOnDelivery, added to the Plugin folder.

[image]

2. Done Re-Build Solution , It copied folder Nop.Plugin.Payments.CashOnDelivery" to \Presentation\Nop.Web\Plugins
3. Still it is not available in Payment Methods page [image]

Please help , Am I missing any step ?

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed the plugin via Configuration -> Plugins menu?